# specifying the One to many relationship with more than one table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a three table which are

1).Category(id,CategoryName)

2).Items(id,imageUrl,name,price,units)

3).Shoppingcart(id,dateCreated)

The USE case is

1)One Category can have multiple items

2)One shopping cart can have multiple items.

so my question is

1)Items are shared between the Category and ShoppingCart How to specify the entity relationship in hibernate.

2)if I have to specify the Quantity for the shopping cart against the Items
i.e The number of items in the shopping cart.
How to create the Entity relation between them.

Comment: As per my understanding of the question you want to create two mappings first between items ----> category and the other one is items ----> cart. Correct me if I am wrong. But why do you need a relationship between category and shopping cart?

Comment: To add further you cannot have a shopping cart directly related to a category but they are indirectly related as an item belongs to a particular category.

Comment: @Archit Sud As per my understanding of the question you want to create two mappings first between items ----> category and the other one is items ----> cart. Correct me if I am wrong. But why do you need a relationship between category and shopping cart?=YES but i dont need the relationship  category and shopping cart

Comment: @ArchitSud WIth your solutions, it will create the relationship between the category and shopping cart?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the relationship will look like:

```
public class Item {

    private int id;

    // all other fields

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;

    /*.........
    Setter Getters
    */


}


public class Category {

    private int id;

    // all other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookCategory", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Item> items;

    /*.........
    Setter Getters
    */


}

public class ShoppingCart {

    private int id;

    // all other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shoppingCart", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Item> items;

    /*.........
    Setter Getters
    */


}
```

Comment: You can add the fetch type parameter in the mapping annotation, by default the fetch type is eager which tells the JPA to get all elements of a relationship when selecting the root entity.

Comment: This will create the relation between the category and shoppingcart.

Comment: where will quantity field be created corresponding to the items?